# Read json vk api c++

Tags: vkontakte-api, c++

Не могу понять как распарсить json с vk api

```
response: {
    count: 12424,
    items: [{
        id: 3252,
        date: 112432523453245,
        out: 0,
        user_id: 1234235,
        read_state: 1,
        title: ' ... ',
        body: 'asf  sadf  ggfreafdsa'
    }]
}
```

Так я получаю key и value

```
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type v, pt.get_child("response"))
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type v2, v.second)
    {
        cout << v2.first << endl; // key
        cout << v2.second.get_value<std::string>() << endl; // value
    }
}
```

Но это же не правильно. Как мне правильно получить value по key??

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html) сообщает:

```
int user_id = pt.get<int>("response.items.user_id");
```